# Trying to create a Tampermonkey userscript to wait for a randomized button pop-up during a video and auto click it

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

This is the pop-up element that occurs randomly throughout the video, I'm trying to make something that will continually search for the buttonID and then left click the element to continue.

```
document.getElementById("overlay").innerHTML="<button class="bcbutton" id="listening" type="button" tabindex="-1" onkeypress="return false;" onclick="register_click();"><img src="http://stemplosion.com/eyesm.jpg/%22%3E<br>I am watching</button>";
```

This is what I've come up with... but it's not working, yet. This is my first time working with JavaScript. Is it even ideal to go by the button id? I considered changing it to the class. Or maybe something to detect the loading of the image?

```js
function autoClick() {
  let listenforit = (document.getElementById("listening"));
  console.log("AUTO CLICKING");
  if (listenforit != null) {
    console.log("AUTO CLICK FOUND LISTENING IT");
    listenforit.click();
  } else {
    console.log("DIDNT FIND IT");
  }
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  autoClick();
}, 200);
```

Comment: So... do you see any of the logs? Errors?

Comment: I'm not sure that `listenforit != null` is a reliable way to determine if the element has loaded into the DOM.   That could be why it's failing.  You should bring up the Javascript Console while viewing the page with the button showing and enter that expression to see what value is returned.    You may have better results with something like this:  `if (typeof listenforit != "undefined" && typeof listenforit != "null"){console.log('found it');};`

Comment: @HereticMonkey sadly the logs didn't tell me much. It showed the loop every 200ms and that it was listening, but when the button would pop-up, I'd see the event but the script didn't seem to execute the click.